# Is there any MsBuild property $(???) for Unit Test executions?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildcommunitytasks, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I am trying to assign a condition to a "Target", 
With the intention of evaluating whether the compilation is produced by the test run or not

[img Run All Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkiH2.png)

[img Singel Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiGVm.png)

But, I do not know what property to use $(?????)

Comment: I think testing itself uses mstest.exe and does not use msbuild at all, so this is impossible?

Comment: Stijn is right, but there's still a way of executing tests after the build. A good example is here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb87a184-6589-454b-bf1c-2e82771fc3aa/example-of-msbuild-with-mstest?forum=msbuild . I'm not entirely sure what you meant with "evaluating whether the compilation is produced by the test run or not", care to elaborate?